# Extend encrypted, large volume on VM

Tags: encryption, lvm, kvm-virtualization

So like the topic says I am trying to resize (extend) one of my VMs using encrypted LVM.

What I've done so far

1. Partitioned and formatted the new drive (using parted, ext4)
2. Added it and extended the LVM on my host (KVM)
3. Resized the VMs image to take up all space on the logical volume

This has gotten me to the point where I can see that the VM has more available space on its (virtual) disk. I have also loaded up a LiveCD and mounted the encrypted LVM. However, I am not sure where to go from here.

Furthermore I'm a bit ashamed to say I've gotten to the point where the number of guides, askubuntu -questions and all other information on the subject has gotten a bit overwhelming: There are too many recipes and I'm not quite sure which one to follow. In addition, most guides deal with < 2TB drives making use of fdisk - which to at least my knowledge "locks up" when going over that size.

Comment: See https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ResizeEncryptedPartitions

Answer (score 0):

I ended up creating a new partition on the (virtual) disk after the existing one, rather then trying to extending it (fdisk didn't work and parted threw various errors messages).

So, final recipe was

1. Create new partition
2. Add new partition as new physical volume in LVM
3. Add the new PV to the VG
4. Extend the encrypted VG
5. Ran cryptsetup resize
6. Rebooted and re-decrypted
7. Resized file system